# Only conditionally re-render when context value updates

Tags: javascript, reactjs, publish-subscribe, react-context

I'm am working on a large React application where performance is critical and unnecessary re-renders are costly.

I have the following example:

```js
const CounterContext = React.createContext();

const CounterProvider = ({children}) => {
    const [counterA, setCounterA] = React.useState(0);
    const [counterB, setCounterB] = React.useState(0);
  
  return (
    <CounterContext.Provider value={{counterA, counterB}}>
      {children}
      <button onClick={() => setCounterA(counterA + 1)}>Counter A ++</button>
      <button onClick={() => setCounterB(counterB + 1)}>Counter B ++</button>
      <button onClick={() => {setCounterA(0); setCounterB(0)}}>reset</button>
    </CounterContext.Provider>
  )
}

const CounterA = () => {
  const value = React.useContext(CounterContext);
  console.log('CounterA re-render');
  return <p>Counter A: {value.counterA}</p>;
}

const CounterB = () => {
  const value = React.useContext(CounterContext);
  console.log('CounterB re-render');
  return <p>Counter B: {value.counterB}</p>;
};

const App = () => {
    return (
    <CounterProvider>
      <CounterA />
      <CounterB />
    </CounterProvider>
  )
};
```

jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/mitchkman/k3hm0vfq/1/

When clicking the **CounterA** button, *both* `CounterA` and `CounterB` components will re-render. I'd like to only re-render `CounterA`, if the `counterA` property in `value` changes.

I'd also like to have the ability to have some form of flexibility for conditional re-rendering. This is a **pseudocode** of what I am trying to do:

```
const MyComponent = () => {

  // Only re-render MyComponent if value.property equals 42
  const value = useContext(MyContext, (value) => value.property === 42);
  ...

};
```

Comment: Do you want to try to prevent any rerendering of `CoutnerA`, or do you want to not expose out the updated `counterA` state value until a predicate is met, i.e. `counterA === 42`? "I'd like to only re-render CounterA, if the counterA property in value changes." This is how it should work out-of-the-box. If you don't want `CounterA` to rerender for other reasons then use the `memo` Higher Order Component and pass a custom `areEqual` function.

Answer (score 0):

You may have to wrap the `counterProvider` to your `App` component. And use `React.memo` to achieve re-rendering only on value changes for that component.

I have done something like here in this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/frosty-hofstadter-1qulg?file=/src/App.js)

**index.js**

```
import { StrictMode } from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { CounterProvider } from "./AppContext";

import App from "./App";

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <StrictMode>
    <CounterProvider>
      <App />
    </CounterProvider>
  </StrictMode>,
  rootElement
);
```

Moved the `counterContext` to a separate file so that you can import and wrap your `App` component.

**AppContext.js**

```
import React, { useCallback } from "react";

const CounterContext = React.createContext();

export const CounterProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [counterA, setCounterA] = React.useState(0);
  const [counterB, setCounterB] = React.useState(0);

  const incrementA = () => {
    setCounterA(counterA + 1);
  };
  const incrementB = () => {
    setCounterB(counterB + 1);
  };

  return (
    <CounterContext.Provider value={{ counterA, counterB }}>
      {children}
      <button onClick={incrementA}>Counter A ++</button>
      <button onClick={incrementB}>Counter B ++</button>
      <button
        onClick={useCallback(() => {
          setCounterA(0);
          setCounterB(0);
        }, [])}
      >
        reset
      </button>
    </CounterContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default CounterContext;
```

Pass the counterA and counterB values to the Counter components as a props, so that `React.memo` can check that value before re-rendering the component.

**App.js**

```
import React from "react";
import CounterContext from "./AppContext";

const CounterA = React.memo(({ value }) => {
  console.log("CounterA re-render");
  return <p>Counter A: {value}</p>;
});

const CounterB = React.memo(({ value }) => {
  console.log("CounterB re-render");
  return <p>Counter B: {value}</p>;
});

const App = () => {
  const value = React.useContext(CounterContext);
  const counterA = value.counterA;
  const counterB = value.counterB;

  console.log(counterA);

  return (
    <>
      <CounterA value={counterA} />
      <CounterB value={counterB} />
    </>
  );
};

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

React normally works by, once it's decided a component needs rerendering, it will unconditionally re-render all children regardless if they need it or not.

The usual way to avoid re-rendering a child is memoization, but that does require properties to be passed into the child via props, not sideways via Context.

In a way, a component using a `useContext` makes it also a child of the Context as well as a child of its actual parent.  Where the parent uses the child you can slip in a `memo` or `useMemo` but not really with Context.

As the other answer explains, you can split each child in twain: the new wrapper part of the child would get the values from the context then conditionally render the real child via `memo`.  So only some of each child runs unconditionally.

Alternatively:

First ensure the Context you're using is memoizing its own values.  This:

```
  const ctx = { arrayOfThings, getThingFnGivenId };
  return <ThingContext.Provider value={ctx}>{children}</ThingContext.Provider>;
```

Even if `getThingFn` is in `useCallback`, and arrayOfThings is in `useRef` or `useMemo` etc, and their references hasn't changed, the ctx wrapper still causes rerendering.  Don't forget the wrapper.

```
  const ctx = useMemo(() => ({ arrayOfThings, getThingFnGivenId }), [...]);
  return <ThingContext.Provider value={ctx}>{children}</ThingContext.Provider>;
```

More importantly: instead of using `arrayOfThings` can you instead have `getThingFn` return a Promise of the arrayOfThings?  (I don't know if this works for this example of hammering on a button over and over (you'd need Promise's big brother, Observables, or some sort of event-and-handler setup), but, )

If so, only return the async function from the context...

```
  return <ThingContext.Provider value={getThingsFn}>{children}</ThingContext.Provider>;
```

And each child will import it, accepting only the id from props, and your existing `useFetch` / `useAsync` function will rerender only that specific child when the context finally makes the data available.

```
const CounterChildA = ({ id }: { id: number}) => {
  const getThingFn = useThingContext();
  const [arrayOfThings, isLoading, error, retryFn] = useAsync(getThingFn, [id]);

  // I render exactly twice just like a component using fetch:
  // once initially, where I call getThingFn(id) for a Promise of Things, 
  // and once more when the promise resolves, filling in arrayOfThings

  return <div>Profit</div>;
}
```

tl;dr If your Context gives you an async function (or wrapper) with stable identity, you can have the child re-render itself in response to the promise resolving instead of to the Context returning an updated array to all children.